# Python FOR loop through dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate over a list which contains dictionaries.

dictionary definition : `{'id' : y, 'value' : (data["value"])}`

I have a for loop as such:

```
for a in (inputs["value"]):
    #print (newStack)
    if a == '+':
        op1, op2 = newStack.pop(), newStack.pop()
        newStack.append(op2 + op1)
    elif a == '-':
        op1, op2 = newStack.pop(), newStack.pop()
        newStack.append(op1 - op2)
...
```

inputs is the list which is sent in, containing the dictionaries.
However I get the error :

> list indices must be integers, not str

The for loop needs to pull out the contents of "value" within the dictionary to compare it to the if statements below.
Could anyone assist as to why I'm getting this error?

Thank you

Comment: This looks very similar to [this dictionary looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772068/list-in-a-dictionary-looping-in-python?rq=1) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputs["value"]` means *"get the thing at dictionary key `"value"` in `inputs`"*.

You want *"get the thing at dictionary key `"value"` **for each dictionary contained in** `inputs`"*:

```
for dict_containing_value in inputs:
    a = dict_containing_value['value']
    # rest as before
```

Answer (score -1):

The way that you wrote, looks like it was declared something like this:

```
data = {'value': (0,1,2,3)}
inputs = {'id' : 'y', 'value' : (data["value"])}
```

If is, than you could simply iterate as:

```
for i in inputs:
    if i is 'value':
        print inputs[i]
```

As the [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python when iterated comes in they keys.

Comment: No, the error here is that `inputs["value"]` is expecting an integer lookup,  i.e. `type(inputs) == list`